DC DC converter as circuit protection
After my previous question on how to protect a C11708MA on the power supply line, I got some ideas and discussions. (Thank you folks!).
As a recap, I want to provide EMI protection to a sensor that takes between 4.75 and 5.25 V (according to the data sheet), and is powered from a power bank, through a Raspberry Pi. Portability is important, and the whole instrument will be in a plastic case. Different components are connected with standard USB cables.
I have an idea that I'd like a review. The TRN 1-0511 DC-DC converter takes between 4.5 and 13.2 VDC and outputs 5 VDC ± 1%, and includes inbuilt surge, ESD, and transients. Am I thinking correctly, it will protect against — at least most — the failure modes? Or does that mean the device will survive them, but potentially pass them along?
One of the answers recommended an LDO that would take up to 20 V. This is limited to 13.2 VDC, but we could add a TVS before that to handle larger surges, as I have a large range to work with.

What kind of emissions are you expecting from the rPi?  If external EMI, is there some reason your wiring inbetween them is highly susceptible? Can this not be improved instead? --> Please show a diagram of the system, including wiring dress, cable type and length.

The wiring are standard USB wires in an indoor environment, but I don't expect to pick up RF noise that would be a problem. My concern are failures somewhere along  the power path.

why would your power bank have surges? Usually batteries are quite stable.

I've added a section to my answer to your previous question, dealing with the use of a DC-DC boost converter.

Adding TVS diodes to supplies almost never hurts, and it's cheap, so, go for it. I can't find any downside.
I'm not sure your switch mode DC/DC (buck/boost or SEPIC internally, almost certainly) supply really helps: transients that you worry about will probably be shorter than what the device regulates. It will, however, introduce additional switching noise. Not exactly what you need when supplying a sensor!
So, you already got good answers. How about you go with them!

Note that an SMPS is a low-pass filter, with cutoff determined by explicit filtering at input and output, and the switching process (possible sampling/mixing effects) and control loop; this may be relevant for transients, though it suggests a simpler route: just an LC filter.

beware that you can excite an LC with a transient to swing and make much more trouble than the transient might have been in the first place :) but some RLC+TVS diode combination is usually the way to go, right? Anyways, we're all stumbling in the dark about what would be appropriate, considering we have absolutely no model of the surges OP is expecting

Yes, some damping is almost always a good idea, such as using electrolytics.

The problem is the tolerances I have to work with. The USB has more swing than what the sensor needs, so almost any silicon you put in between gets me out of spec. A DC-DC like this one (or a bit higher) followed by a LDO with a wide input range, but now I have more margin.

@MarcusMüller the surges I could expect is whatever failure modes are in the system. Maybe I am overthinking this whole thing.

yeah, stepping up consciously to, say, 6.3 V (there's probably fixed-output switching step-up regulators for that!), and then going down by 1.3 V is going to give you relatively much headroom. As Tim says, any switching regulator inherently is a low-pass filter, but you'd really want to get rid of "sharp" overvoltage inputs with a TVS.

@Davidmh hm, we can't know your system's failure modes!
